# Back Button issue

Tags: android

I am creating a small application. In View Page I am performing update and delete operations from database and displaying data on the top (ex 10 records). At the bottom I have 2 buttons, Edit and delete. If user clicks Edit button, it redirects to Edit page. In Edit page I am displaying content for editing also I have 2 buttons update and cancel. If user click update again I am redirecting(using start activity) to view page. It is not displaying new records. I went back to main page and then I clicked view page now it is updated How to solve this? Another problem is at the same if user clicks back button it is going all page which i went (through redirected page).

For example, first I click view page from main page. In view page am doing edit and delete operation.After completing this it goes to view page. Here I am clicking back button it is going previous page that is edit or delete page which I have performed last. I need to go main page from view (after performing edit or delete op) How to do this?

Comment: Kumar you should just ask one question at a time. You should edit this question down to one and create a new question for the other.

Comment: You may also want to display some code to help us better understand the problem.

Comment: I'd also suggest using some more punctuation. Reading this question is really quite difficult at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

For your problem with the user editing data and the results are not being displayed make sure you are populating it with your new data. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) for more info.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);

    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);

    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

    mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) : null;
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) : null;
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
    }
}
```